# Command parameter autocompletion like "xe"

Tags: linux, command-line, autocomplete, xen

I noticed today, when working with XenServer's CLI, that the xe command allows autocompletion with the 'tab' character not only for files, but for parameters too!

For example if I write xe vm-[tab] I see vm-list, vm-clone, vm-copy and so on. These are not files, these are parameters of the xe command!

How can I archive this with other commands? How does it work?

Comment: It works with other commands out of the box. For example on Debian-based OSes you can use `apt-get in[Tab]`. I don't know how it works, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this to be a good guide on how completion works:

using the bash complete command[1](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/more-using-bash-complete-command)

in short, there's some bash scripts doing the work for you and as time goes by the packagers are adding more scriptlets to `/etc/bash_completion.d`, such as the `xen-tools` script.

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!